# Create a column by selecting random elements from a given list in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Create a column by selecting random elements  from a given list in pandas.

```
ID 
1
2
3
4
5

list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9]
```

Then I would like to create a column named Probability by choosing an element randomly from the above list with replacement.

Expected output: (one of the random output out of 36 combinations)

```
ID    Probability
1     0.8
2     0.1
3     0.1
4     0.5
5.    0.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged numpy, you can use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

l = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': range(1,6)})
df['Probability'] = np.random.choice(l, size=df.shape[0]) # By default replace=True

df
   ID  Probability
0   1          0.1
1   2          0.1
2   3          0.8
3   4          0.3
4   5          0.2
```